# where is the calibration info of usb_cam?

Tags: calibration, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have used camera_calibration to generate my desired calibration info .
but ,how can i apply this data to my application.
i can see the original calibration info by

```
" rostopic echo /usb_cam/camera_info".
and how can i find the location of the "/usb_cam/camera_info",
```

then edit it by replacing by the previous calibration.

in a word,where does my camera driver store its calibration information ?
thanks!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45291/where-is-the-calibration-info-of-usb_cam?/) by [bobliao](https://answers.ros.org/users/2976/bobliao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-10-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The standard place to put the camera calibration file is in `~/.ros/camera_info/`. For example the camera calibration node will export the calibration result for `usb_cam` to `~/.ros/camera_info/usb_cam.yaml`.

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2012-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) on 2013-05-15**:
I use the usb_cam driver, I calibrated the camera, but I don't have a camera_info folder in ~/.ros.

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2013-07-13**:
You have to calibrate the camera using camera_calibration (see http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_calibration/Tutorials/MonocularCalibration) and then generate the yaml file using camera_calibration_parsers (see http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_calibration_parsers). Copy the yaml file into that folder.